# Gmail API in GAS: Refreshing Interface on State Change?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I'm currently writing using Google-Apps-Scripts to do change labels on threads and messages. When the script completes, the payloads are moved, but the display on the user frontend does not change until the user interacts with Gmail.

Is there a way to push a refresh command to Gmail? How can I gracefully display "job's done" to the user so they know that messages are now appropriately labeled?

I am working directly against the Gmail API, not GmailApp. I discovered ActionResponseBuilder.setStateChanged(), but the problem is I am currently not working with any sort of frontend interface. This is all in the background.

Here is an abbreviated example of some of the code I'm using to grab messages to modify (as requested):

```
function changeLabel(ids,oldLabel,newLabel) {
  Gmail.Users.Messages.batchModify({
    "ids":ids,
    "addLabelIds":oldLabel,
    "removeLabelIds":newLabel
  },"me");
}

function start() {
  // Labels to work with
  const FOO = "Label_5095729546757874255";
  const BAR = "Label_5102306845672214551";

  // API call to retrieve list of messages by Label
  var msgIdsByLabel = new MessageIndex(FOO);  

  // API call to retrieve message contents
  var payloadMessages = new Messages(msgIdsByLabel);

  var manifestMessagesToMove = [];

  for (var i=0;i < Object.keys(payloadMessages.response).length; i++) {
    // Criteria for selecting messages to move goes here
    manifestMessagesToMove[i] = payloadMessages.response[i].id;
  }

  // Change labels of Message Ids
  changeLabel(manifestMessagesToMove,FOO,BAR);

  // ??? Refresh Gmail Interface ???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible.

The Gmail UI can't be refreshed from Apps Script as it is run in the cloud as a separate session to that which is being viewed in the web browser by a user. The two aren't connected - and the same goes for the Gmail API.

If you don't have a front-end interface (aka a Gmail Add-on utilising `CardService`) then there is not a way of displaying a message to the user, either. The refresh will have to be done manually.